# socketIO 404 in nextjs not found

Tags: next.js, socket.io

I'm having problems connecting to Socket Io. Currently I've tried various ways by moving the sockethandler file to the root of the "API" folder then trying to change the version but it still doesn't work.

and below for the "SocketHandler" file, the route path is "/api/whatsapp/SocketHandler.ts"

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io'
import QRCode from 'qrcode'
import * as whatsapp from "wa-multi-session";


const SocketHandler = (req, res) => {
  if (res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log('Socket is already running')
  } else {
    console.log('Socket is initializing')
    const io = new Server(res.socket.server)
    res.socket.server.io = io

    io.on('connection', socket => {
      console.log("connection")
      // Mendengarkan pesan dari klien
      socket.on('qrCode', async (session: string) => {
        console.log(session)
        if(session){
          // Check Session Name if Exist
          const sessionName = session;
          const isSessionExist = whatsapp.getSession(sessionName!);

          if (isSessionExist == null) {
            //Custom Path Session
            whatsapp.setCredentialsDir(process.env.SESSION_PATH);

            //Create New Session
            const session = await whatsapp.startSession(sessionName);


            //Return Response
            whatsapp.onQRUpdated(async (data) => {
                const qr = await QRCode.toDataURL(data.qr);                
                io.emit('qrCodeResponse', qr);
            });

            whatsapp.onConnecting(async (data) => {
                io.emit('connectingSession', data);
            });

            whatsapp.onConnected(async (data) => {
                io.emit('connectedSession', data);
            });


        } else {
           io.emit('messageError', 'Session Already Exist');
        }
        }
      });
    })
  }
  res.end()
}
export default SocketHandler
```

and the following are for the components contained in the jsx file

```
import {
  Button,
  Input,
  Modal,
  ModalBody,
  ModalContent,
  ModalFooter,
  ModalHeader,
  useDisclosure,
} from "@nextui-org/react";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import io from "socket.io-client";
import { useTheme as useNextTheme } from "next-themes";


export const AddSessions = () => {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
  const [qrCode, setQrCode] = React.useState("");
  const [isImageVisible, setIsImageVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const [isQrCodeVisible, setIsQrCodeVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const { setTheme, theme } = useNextTheme();

  const SOCKET_URL = '/api/whatsapp/SocketHandler'; // Ganti dengan URL server Anda

  let socket = io(SOCKET_URL);


  useEffect(() => {
    socketInitializer();

  },)


  const socketInitializer = async () => {
    await fetch('/api/whatsapp/SocketHandler')
    socket = io()

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      // console.log('connected')
    })

    socket.once('qrCodeResponse', (response) => {

      if (isQrCodeVisible === false ) {
        setQrCode(response);
        successNotify("Succesfully generated QR Code");
        setIsImageVisible(true);

        //for stoping the loop emit
        setIsQrCodeVisible(true);
      }

    });
    socket.once('connectedSession', (response) => {
      if (response === process.env.SESSION_NAME) {
        successNotify("Succesfully connected to session");
        resetState();

        //set timeout 2,5 second before reload
        setTimeout(() => {
          window.location.reload();
        }, 2500)
      }
    });



    socket.on('messageError', (error: string) => {
      failedNotify(error);
    });
  }

  const successNotify = (message) => {
    toast.success(message, {
      position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT
    });
    setIsImageVisible(true);
  };

  const failedNotify = (message) => {
    toast.error(message, {
      position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,
    });
  };

  const resetState = () => {
    setQrCode("");
    setIsImageVisible(false);
    handleClose();
  }

  const handleClose = () => {
    setQrCode("");
    setIsImageVisible(false);
    onClose();
  }

  function handlerAddSession() {
    const session = process.env.SESSION_NAME

    socket.emit('qrCode', session);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <>
        <ToastContainer
          position="top-right"
          autoClose={2800}
          hideProgressBar={false}
          newestOnTop={false}
          closeOnClick
          rtl={false}
          pauseOnFocusLoss
          draggable
          pauseOnHover
          // @ts-ignore
          theme={theme} />

        <Button onPress={onOpen} color="primary">
          Add Sessions
        </Button>
        <Modal
          isOpen={isOpen}
          onClose={handleClose}
          placement="top-center"
        >
          <ModalContent>
            {(onClose) => (
              <>
                <ModalHeader className="flex flex-col gap-1">
                  Add Sessions
                </ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                  {isImageVisible && (
                    <img
                      src={qrCode}
                      alt="Qr Code"
                      id="qrCode"
                      style={{ maxWidth: '100%', maxHeight: '400px' }}
                    />
                  )}

                </ModalBody>
                <ModalFooter>
                  <Button color="danger" variant="flat" onClick={handleClose}>
                    Close
                  </Button>
                  {!isImageVisible && (
                    <Button id="addSession" color="primary" onPress={handlerAddSession}>
                      Add Session
                    </Button>
                  )}

                </ModalFooter>
              </>
            )}
          </ModalContent>
        </Modal>
      </>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I made the following code in nextjs